# Can not access network with Mac OS X 10.10.5 Proxifier info sf_connect_out xx allready connected

Tags: macos, mac, network, proxy

After I left for a while, the Mac locked screen. When I got back and logged in again, the Proxifier's connections area shows this info:

[image]

Lots of apps on my Mac including Chrome, Safari, Evernote, Twitter etc. can not access the network anymore. Anyone know how to solve this?